# Why does Mule ArrayList.contains() gives incorrect value for an empty/null string

Tags: java, arraylist, mule

I've a conditional expression in my `Mule 3.3.0` config like this:

```
<when expression="#[places.contains(message.payload)]">
```

.
.
.

```
</when>
```

`places` is a local variable declared as

```
<set-variable variableName="places" value="{'Buenos Aires', 'Córdoba', 'La Plata'}"/>
```

Before doing above conditional expression, there is an `XSL` transformer which sets the payload. Conditional expression works fine if payload is non empty but in cases where xsl transformer doesn't return a result and `#[payload]` is `empty`, still above conditional statement returns `true`.

How can I correct this?

**EDIT**
`XSL` transformer is declared as:

```
<xm:xslt-transformer xsl-file="xsl/getPlaces.xslt" returnClass="java.lang.String"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your configuration:

- The expression you use to create a list is not correct: it is actually just creating a `String`. Use a MEL expression instead:

  ```
  <set-variable variableName="places"
                value="#[{'Buenos Aires', 'Córdoba', 'La Plata'}]"/>
  ```
- Use MEL `contains` to find the String payload in this list of places:

  ```
  #[places contains message.payload]
  ```

Comment: I edited the question to show that xsl transformer is already declared with returnClass as `java.lang.String`. I tried your change but still the same result. `#[places.contains(message.payload)]` or `#[places.contains(message.payloadAs(java.lang.String))]` returns `true` when xslt doesn't return any result element

Comment: I think I've spotted a second issue: `places` is defined as a `String` not a `List` of `String`s because you do not use an expression in `set-variable`.

Comment: Changing places to as suggested in above edit throws `[Error: unable to resolve method: [Ljava.lang.Object;.contains(java.lang.String) [arglength=1]]
[Near : {... Unknown ....}]` exception. Now, places is of type `Object` rather than `String`. I was wondering similar thing when I wrote it in first place that how does the variable gets the `type`. But as it let me use `List.contains()`, I thought may be its assigning type based on value.

Comment: Actually `[Ljava.lang.Object` tells us `places` is a `List` of objects. I don't get why `.contains()` doesn't work on it. Let's try with MEL `contains`, ie `#[places contains message.payload]`.

Comment: This works exactly as it should like `String.equals()`. Though I don't understand why `List.contains()` in Mule fails but happy that `MEL contains` works well. Thank you David for working on it and please add this to your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Cool! Glad it works. I reviewed my response accordingly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The places variable should be accessed in the following way:

```
#[flowVars['places'].contains(message.payload)]
```

Comment: Still same result with this change